# Core Data: Setting Entity.Attribute, Type Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, core-data

I'm currently trying to set up my entity by filling in the required attributes. I am doing this by parsing an XML response and assigning the attributes as they come up. The issue that I am running into is that I have what seems to be a type mismatch that results in my attribute set function throwing an "incorrect selector sent to function" error. I have gone into the debugger and noticed that always before assigning to my custEntity.name attribute, my type seems to be of NSCFString instead of NSString. I have done some searching as well as some tests and attempted fixes of my own but have been unable to get anywhere. Here is some relevant code and its effects.

Auto Generated and Combined into one file with my other entity definition, DataModelObject.h:

```
@interface Checkpoint : NSManagedObject {
    @private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject * myRoute;
@end
```

DataModelObject.m

```
@implementation Checkpoint
@dynamic name;
@dynamic lat;
@dynamic lon;
@dynamic myRoute;
@end
```

What my current code looks like as a result of a suggestion to someone else with a somewhat similar problem elsewhere:

```
NSString *chkptName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
checkpoint.name = [[NSString stringWithString:chkptName] stringValue];
```

This seems like some serious overkill to me, though I'm new to Objective-c and iPhone development so I dont know, it may be necessary, in any case this does not work. Before the execution of the second line the value of chkptName is the correct, human readable string that I would like to assign. In theory, if I understand the second line correctly, I simply re-declare an NSString with the value of ckptName, and the read out the actual value of it again with stringValue, which should be the same as getting the value of chkptName. However its in the second line that my app crashes with sigAbrt and when I attempt to check the values of my variable it shows that its of type NSCFString, with an invalid summary for the value. At this point I am at a loss on how to fix this. I have correctly modified entity attributes before and have not run into this problem before.

It is probably also worth noting that I started this out much simpler:

```
checkpoint.name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

But this yielded the same sigAbrt and incorrect selector error.

Edit: Full Error as requested:

2011-08-02 07:25:00.544 MyApp[16011:207] -[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c174e0
2011-08-02 07:25:00.545 MyApp[16011:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c174e0'

Edit2: Debugger Output:

```
(gdb) po checkpoint
<Checkpoint: 0x5a30730> (entity: (null); id: (null) ; data: {})
(gdb) po [checkpoint class]
Checkpoint
(gdb) po [checkpoint entity]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
```

Any clarification that you can provide is much appreciated, if there is also some relevant code that I missed please ask and I will be happy to provide it if possible. Thanks!

-Karoly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a careful look and verify that your `checkpoint` variable really is an instance of the `Checkpoint` class.

1. Verify that the class is properly setup in your Core Data model.
2. Set a breakpoint at run-time and print the object in the debugger: **`po checkpoint`**.
3. Verify the entity of the object at run-time with: **`po [checkpoint entity]`**.

Comment: You can also use 'po [checkpoint class]' to see what type of class it is.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question with the print out results. It seems that [checkpoint entity] is nil which may be the problem, though I am unable to set anything to it to change any values so I dont know. I do allocate my checkpoint variable 2 lines beforehand.

Comment: @Karol S - This suggest that the `Checkpoint` instance has not been instantiated correctly with the entity description. Do you use `+[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]` to instantiate new managed objects such as the `Checkpoint` class?

Comment: Woooooow... I honestly cant believe that I didn't look into this a bit more earlier, especially since I correctly instantiated a managed object a few calls earlier. That was the problem, am I now correctly assigning values using checkpoint.name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"]; and can verify that in the debugger console. Now to fix the rest of the problems haha. Thanks for the help PeyloW and ThePaddedCell!

Comment: @Karoly S - Yup that assignment should be OK. No problem, that is why we are here: To help and get helped :).

Comment: Hey PeyloW, I don't mean to bring this back from the dead, but its the second time I've run into the following error that I have no idea how to fix. I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on my     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); in main. The debugger shows no stack so I have nothing to go off of. I've walked through with a breakpoint and checked my objects and my core data part seems to be working correctly(Though part of the way through it just turns to assembly so I cant follow it), its just crashing somewhere else. You wouldnt happen to know why this could be?

Comment: @Karoly - Post it as a new question, and I'll have a look.

Comment: I managed to fix it by just going through my recently added code piece by piece. I found that xcode gave me a potential memory error warning when I built my project using Cmd+Shft+B about how I was freeing an NSString variable of mine. It looks like I was just releasing it once more than I should have. In any case, if it comes back I'll ask it as a new question and inbox you with a link from here. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that the question has already been answered, but maybe for future reference:

If you get an error like this:

`2011-08-02 07:25:00.544 MyApp[16011:207] -[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

It's pretty useful to really look at what it's saying:

`unrecognized selector sent to instance` means that an object has received a message that it cannot respond to or doesn't know how to.

`-[NSCFString stringValue]` shows you what message was sent (`stringValue`) and which object it was sent to (`NSCFString`).

From the message in the error  we see that the error most probably happened when you called

```
checkpoint.name = [[NSString stringWithString:chkptName] stringValue];
```

Since that seems to be the only place where you call the message `stringValue` on an object (from what you've posted). And `NSCFString` is simply a subclass of `NSString`.

So you can't call `stringValue` on an `NSString` (which makes sense too). Just for clarification, but as I've read the issue has already been resolved. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay Octoshape, I have posted the full error near the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Karoly S I've edited my reply and added some useful information if you happen to run in another error like this one. Hope this helps you in the future :) glad you could fix the problem!